# Redux: data manipulation is a responsability of the action or of the reducer?

Tags: redux, react-redux

My action fetch an url and got a json.

I need to transform this json into an array of objects and set into the state.

I ask you: **Where must placed the business logic to transform json into an array of object?**

Must be placed

1. into the action code dispatching an action with a 'ready-to-use' payload,

or

2. into the reducers code, which receive the 'raw data' as json in the payload, then transform into an array of objects and put into the state

?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Redux doc](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html)

> Actions are payloads of information that send data from your application to your store.
>
> Actions describe the fact that something happened, but don't specify
>   how the application's state changes in response. This is the job of
>   reducers.

So I will go for the option #2: doing it into the reducers code, which will receive the 'raw data' as json in the payload, then transform into an array of objects and put into the state.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the doc and for a short and clear answer.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Reducers are supposed to be pure functions (no side effects), so you should transform it before. You can do this using any utils after you get your data in your async action creators. In the stated case it's ok to put it in reducer code only if there's no need to process the data but only create a new array using the json.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but i would like to share my thoughts. Your situation is referred to as an async action in the redux documents. And while:

> Actions are payloads of information that send data from your application to your store.
>
> Actions describe the fact that something happened, but don't specify how the application's state changes in response. This is the job of reducers.

Async actions are a little more complex and as shown in the redux documentation under Advanced Tutorials: [Redux Async Actions](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions):

```
export const RECEIVE_POSTS = 'RECEIVE_POSTS'

function receivePosts(subreddit, json) {
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_POSTS,
    subreddit,
    posts: json.data.children.map(child => child.data),
    receivedAt: Date.now()
  }
}
```

They suggest you parse the async response before you send it to the reducer. So i think option 1 is the correct one.

Hope this helps!